# Kafka stream : class cast exception during left join

Tags: left-join, apache-kafka-streams

I am new to kafka. I am trying to leftJoin a kafka stream (named as **inputStream**) to kafka-table(named as **detailTable**) where the kafka-stream is built as:

```
//The consumer to consume the input topic
Consumed<String, NotifyRecipient> inputNotificationEventConsumed = Consumed
        .with(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY_SERDE, Constants.CONSUMER_VALUE_SERDE);


//Now create the stream that is directly reading from the topic
KStream<NotifyKey, NotifyVal> initialInputStream =
        streamsBuilder.stream(properties.getInputTopic(), inputNotificationEventConsumed);


//Now re-key the above stream for the purpose of left join
KStream<String, NotifyVal> inputStream = initialInputStream
          .map((notifyKey,notifyVal) ->
              KeyValue.pair(notifyVal.getId(),notifyVal)
          );
```

And the kafka-table is created this way:

```
//The consumer for the table
Consumed<String, Detail> notifyDetailConsumed =
          Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Constants.DET_CONSUMER_VALUE_SERDE);

//Now consume from the topic into ktable
KTable<String, Detail> detailTable = streamsBuilder
          .table(properties.getDetailTopic(), notifyDetailConsumed);
```

Now I am trying to join the **inputStream** to the **detailTable** as:

```
  //Now join
  KStream<String,Pair<Long, SendCmd>> joinedStream = inputStream
          .leftJoin(detailTable, valJoiner)
          .filter((key,value)->value!=null);
```

I am getting an **error** from which it seems that during the join, the key and value of the **inputStream** were tried to **cast into** the default key-serde and default value-serde and getting a class cast exception.

Not sure how to fix this and need help there.
Let me know if I should provide more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use a `map()`, key and value type might have changes and thus you need to specify the correct Serdes  via `Joined.with(...)` as third parameter to `.leftJoin()`.

Comment: Because of that reason, I had to use "through" after "map"

Comment: Using `through()` should not be necessary -- Kafka Streams should create a repartition topic automatically for you for this case, because it should detect that `map()` was used before `KStream#leftJoin(KTable,...)` -- for this case, the Serdes from `Joined.with()` would be used to write and read to/from the repartition topic. Can you verify if this work for you?